# Как создать datagridview в unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-android

нужна помощь у меня есть таблица в базе статистика прохождения, и я бы хотел вывести на сцене статистику ученика, но казус в том что тут нет datagridview, и не знаю что мне теперь делать. Помогите пожалуйста, буду очень признателен.

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, то в юнити нет подобных компонентов. Вы можете например попробовать использовать [сетку](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/script-GridLayoutGroup.html), можете позиционировать объекты вручную (как например в [этом видео](https://youtu.be/iAbaqGYdnyI)), либо установить сторонние компоненты, например [этот](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/gui/ui-table-137867). Но замечу, я не Unity разработчик, из-за чего могу ошибаться.

Comment: https://youtube.com/watch?v=CGsEJToeXmA